# Count occasion measurement times in longitudinal data

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, count

I have a longitudal dataset, where the same subjects are measured at different occasions in time.
For instance:

```
dd=data.frame(subject_id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,9,9),income=c(rnorm(16,50000,250)))
```

I should write something able to tell me how many subjects have been counted only once, twice, three times,... In the example above, the number of subjects measured at only one occasion in time is 4, the number of subjects measured twice is 3,...
That's my attempt for counting, for instance, how many subjects have been measured only twice:

```
library(dplyr)
s.two=dd %>%   group_by(subject_id) %>%   filter(n() == 2) %>%   ungroup()
length(s.two$subject_id)/2
```

But since I have very heterogenous clusters (ranging from 1 to 24 observations per subject), this implies that I should write  planty of rows. Is there something more efficient I can do?

The objective is to have a summary of the size of the clusters (and the cluster is the subject_id). For instance, let say I have 1,000 clusters. I wanna know, how many of them are made up of subjects observed just once, twice... And so, 50 out of 1000 clusters are made up of subjects observed just one occasion in time ; 300 out of 1000 clusters are made up of subjects observed just two occasions in time...
With this info, I shall construct a table to add in my report

Comment: Do you want a double count - e.g `dd %>% count(subject_id) %>% count(times = n)` or `with(dd, table(table(subject_id)))`?

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe my question was not entirely clear. Let me add the objective of the coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `summarize`. After this you can still filter with `filter(n == 2)`.

```r
library(dplyr)

dd <- data.frame(
  subject_id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9),
  income = c(rnorm(16, 50000, 250))
)


dd |>
  group_by(subject_id) |>
  summarise(n = n())
#> # A tibble: 9 × 2
#>   subject_id     n
#>        <dbl> <int>
#> 1          1     3
#> 2          2     3
#> 3          3     2
#> 4          4     1
#> 5          5     1
#> 6          6     1
#> 7          7     1
#> 8          8     2
#> 9          9     2
```

---

If you use `mutate` instead of `summarize` and filter then, you will get

```
dd |>
  group_by(subject_id) |>
  mutate(n = n()) |> 
  filter(n ==2)

subject_id income     n
       <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
1          3 49675.     2
2          3 50306.     2
3          8 49879.     2
4          8 50202.     2
5          9 49783.     2
6          9 49834.     2
```

---

**NEW EDIT**
Maybe you mean this:

```
dd |>
  group_by(subject_id) |> 
  summarise(n = n()) |> 
  mutate(info = glue::glue(
    'There are {n} times {subject_id} out of {max(subject_id)} groups')) |> 
  select(info)

# A tibble: 9 × 1
  info                               
  <glue>                             
1 There are 3 times 1 out of 9 groups
2 There are 3 times 2 out of 9 groups
3 There are 2 times 3 out of 9 groups
4 There are 1 times 4 out of 9 groups
5 There are 1 times 5 out of 9 groups
6 There are 1 times 6 out of 9 groups
7 There are 1 times 7 out of 9 groups
8 There are 2 times 8 out of 9 groups
9 There are 2 times 9 out of 9 groups
```

---

**Next** which would be @`Ritchie Sacramento` 's solution

```
dd |>
  group_by(subject_id) |> 
  summarise(no_of_occurences = n()) |> 
  count(no_of_occurences) 

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  no_of_occurences     n
             <int> <int>
1                1     4
2                2     3
3                3     2
```

Comment: I'm so sorry for wasting your time, but that's not the outcome I was looking for. I've just made my question more clear

Comment: @Maximilian Maybe I am still not getting it. But to me it seems that the first part of my answer is what you are looking for. If you want to make a table out of this to be used in a `markdown` -document for instance you can add `knit::kable(format='pipe')` and paste the outcome into your document.

Comment: The first table fully answers to my question. The only problem is that it is hard to attain the info from that table. It correctly says that subject one has been measured three times, subject two three times... What I'm looking for is a more synthetic info. I'd just read the total number of clusters where subjects are observed just once, twice... In my example, I'd read: "number of clusters made up of subjects only observed once = 4 ". This means that 4/9 of the clusters are of size 1. And then, 3/9 of clustes are of size 2, and 2/9 of clusters are of size 3

Comment: Still not very sure about what you mean, but please have a look to the new edit

Comment: I have to specify the size of clusters of my dataset in the report. I was just looking for a more efficient way to understand the size of clusters. But still, I do not need to know how many times each subject is counted. The answer I'm looking for is different, i.e., how many DIFFERENT subjects have been countend just once, twice, three times...

Comment: Next trial, please check